# Lightweight and low-latency Java network library?

Tags: java, networking, nio, netty

I'm working on a client-server pair where the multithreaded client performs thousands invocations of the server per second and the first priority is to achieve a minimal latency. Throughput should be high as well. Both client and server are written in Java, communication semantics is quite simple (put/get operations).

What is the best Java network library/framework for these requirements? Servers like Tomacat/Jetty seems to be heavyweight. I'm thinking about MINA or Netty, but I'm not sure that  these asynchronous libs will provide a stable low latency under heavy workload.

Comment: You are talking about "the [..] client performs thousands invocations". Do you really just have *one* (or very few clients)? Frameworks based on java nio (netty/mina) shine when they are handling very many clients (simultanous connections), but that doesn't necessarily mean these clients perform many invocations. tomcat uses http, whereas mina/netty are more geared towards using tcp directly.

Comment: Yes, I have only a few client applications and each application has a relatively small number of threads (~20). So, a total number of connections is not extremely high.

Comment: Almost all non-blocking network libraries produce a lot of garbage as they handle messages. It becomes very hard to be real time when you have the GC interference. I suggest you take a look at [CoralReactor](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralreactor/), which produces zero garbage.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to try [kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to communicate on the same machine you can try something like [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle)
 which can support over a million persisted messages per second with sub-microsecond round trip times.

If you want low latency between machines, you need to look very carefully at your hardware. For commodity hardware your round trip latency will be 100 micro-seconds per more. With specialist hardware you are looking closer to 20 micro-seconds.

Or you could communicate on the same box and get much lower latencies. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Jocket](https://github.com/pcdv/jocket). It shares some concepts with Java Chronicle but is directly targeted at replacing the standard Socket implementation.

RTT latency is below the microsecond for a ping-pong between processes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need ultra-high performance and throughput, I recommend using raw sockets (check out Socket and ServerSocket - there may be an nio version too). This will free you from the overhead contained in HTTP and other protocols

Comment: Socket and ServerSocket are not 'raw sockets'. They are TCP sockets. Raw sockets cannot be used from pure Java,